# SIP channel format. Asterisk

Tags: sip, asterisk

I get Bridge event from Asterisk. Channel2:SIP/727-000000e3. 727 is a number of phone. What does the rest part mean(-000000e3)? Thank you.

**UPD**
I have found this in http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+channels

When you have an established SIP connection, its channel name will be in this format:

SIP/peer-id

peer is the identified peer and id is a random identifier to be able to uniquely identify multiple calls from a single peer.

---

So for each call that part will be unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a unique identifier for that channel technology type over the lifetime of an Asterisk instance.  So if you stop Asterisk, you are no longer guaranteed to not have repeats of that identifier.

As an implementation detail, the number is not unique, but a monotonically increasing hexadecimal number with respect to the channel technology type.